# How can i skip printing cucumber scenarios in console output?

Tags: java, cucumber

I dont want to print cucumber test scenarios in the console logs or in git-log. Is there a way i can suppress them ?
For Example :
Scenario: Valid Palindrome
Given I entered string "Refer"
When I test it for Palindrome
Then the result should be "true"

Scenario: Invalid Palindrome
Given I entered string "Coin"
When I test it for Palindrome
Then the result should be "false"

I dont want to see these line in the output.

Comment: How are you running Cucumber?

Comment: We are running with a cucumber.class - Cucumber-junit-1.2.6.jar